# WEB API C# REPONSE HANGS (HttpWebResponse)http.GetResponse()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

Am doing an WEB API .net 4.62 that /Token with username password and grant_type to get access token once its generated i woul like to get it value of access_token.This does not happen but when i take the same code to a windows form aplication I am able to get it what could be wrong. It hangs on    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)http.GetResponse())

```
try
            {
                string myParameters = "username=value1&password=value2&grant_type=password";
                string baseAddress = "http://localhost:50128/token";
                var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(baseAddress));
                http.Accept = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                http.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                http.Method = "POST";

                string parsedContent = myParameters;
                ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                Byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(parsedContent);
                Stream newStream = http.GetRequestStream();
                newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                newStream.Close();
                http.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
                http.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
                http.Timeout = 2000;
               using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)http.GetResponse())
                {
                    var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                    var content = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    JObject json = JObject.Parse(content);
                    var message = json.SelectToken("access_token").ToString();
                    Console.Write(message);
                }
            }
            
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Handle the exceptions that could appear
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

change the using block like this and also convert your function to "async".

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await Task.Factory.FromAsync(http.BeginGetResponse, http.EndGetResponse, null).ConfigureAwait(false))

let me know if it works.

Comment: Didnt work but from the same project if i  add a .aspx webpage and paste the same code it runs  I think the  problem could be  am access the token  from a controller that generates the token public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {           using (UserAuthentication OBJ = new UserAuthentication())   }